# Read all InputStream values at once into a byte[] array

Tags: java, android, inputstream

Is there a way to read all InputStream values at once without a need of using some `Apache IO lib`?

I am reading IR signal and saving it from the `InputStream` into the `byte[]` array. While debugging, I have noticed that it works only if I put a delay there, so that I read all bytes at once and then process it.

Is there a smarter way to do it?

CODE:

```
 public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
        int numberOfBytes;
        removeSharedPrefs("mSharedPrefs");
        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                numberOfBytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                Thread.sleep(700);  //If I stop it here for a while, all works fine, because array is fully populated
                if (numberOfBytes  > 90){
                    // GET AXIS VALUES FROM THE SHARED PREFS
                    String[] refValues = loadArray("gestureBuffer", context);
                    if (refValues!=null && refValues.length>90) {
                        int incorrectPoints;
                        if ((incorrectPoints = checkIfGesureIsSameAsPrevious(buffer, refValues, numberOfBytes)) < 5) {
                           //Correct
                        } else {
                           //Incorrect
                        }
                    }
                    saveArray(buffer, numberOfBytes);
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Transmission of the data was corrupted.");
                }
                buffer = new byte[100];
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, numberOfBytes, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't ever assume that when you ask to read N bytes, you will get N bytes. You can get 0 to N bytes, but you can never be sure you will get N bytes. Always use a loop to read. Adding a sleep() is not a solution. It probably happens to work because it's enough for the bytes to be available, but that will depend on the network, the machine, etc. There are shortcuts methods to read a stream completely in Java 7 and later, but not in Java 6, AFAIK. Maybe android has such utilities, but I don't know Android enough to know. Anyway, it's simple to write it yourself.

Comment: @JBNizet, thank you. I will try to do the loop thing, if you wish you may answer the question. Perhaps give me some example code. Thanks a lot. Can you also please check if Sebastians answer is correct?

Comment: I think it's correct, yes. I don't know nio very well.Why don't you test it?

Comment: I am going to test it, I am just in a rush. Sorry for that.

Comment: Define 'all InputStream values'. Mostly you just have to keep reading. Sleeps in network code don't solve anything really. Changing from streams to NIO isn't necessary.

Comment: I send first 4 bytes, then there is a little pause and then I send the rest 95 bytes. However, I don't want the code to go further until I have all 99 bytes.

Comment: So block and loop until you have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

My old answer is wrong, see EJPs comment! Please don't use it. The behaviour of ByteChannels depend on wether InputStreams are blocking or not.

So this is why I would suggest, you just copy [IOUtils.read](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from Apache Commons:

```
public static int read(final InputStream input, final byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
    int remaining = buffer.length;
    while (remaining > 0) {
        final int location = buffer.length - remaining;
        final int count = input.read(buffer, location, remaining);
        if (count == -1) { // EOF
            break;
        }
        remaining -= count;
    }
    return buffer.length - remaining;
}
```

---

Old answer:

You can use ByteChannels and read into a ByteBuffer:

```
ReadableByteChannel c = Channels.newChannel(inputstream);
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(numBytesExpected);
int numBytesActuallyRead = c.read(buf);
```

This read method is attempting to read as many bytes as there is remaining space in the buffer. If the stream ends before the buffer is fully filled, the number of bytes actually read is returned. See [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html).

Comment: Doesn't really help,and the allocation of a new `ByteBuffer` per read is wasteful. You can write equivalent streams code without that. `InputStream.read()` returns a count too.

Comment: I am going to try it as soon as I get home. Thanks a lot Sebastian and @EJP.